# How do I resolve this error running create-nuxt-app?

Tags: node.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

[Nuxt.js](https://nuxtjs.org/)/[Vue.js](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/) app: command not found

**Error:**

> dell@Himanshu-sharma:~/Workspace/Web/vue-nuxt$ sudo npm i create-nuxt-app -g[sudo] password for dell:
> /home/dell/.npm-global/bin/create-nuxt-app -> /home/dell/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/create-nuxt-app/cli.js

> create-nuxt-app@1.2.2
> added 413 packages in 28.445s
> dell@Himanshu-sharma:~/Workspace/Web/vue-nuxt$ create-nuxt-app myapp
> bash: create-nuxt-app: command not found

Comment: `/home/dell/.npm-global/bin` needs to be in your `PATH`. Otherwise call it via full path: `/home/dell/.npm-global/bin/create-nuxt-app myapp`

Comment: Thanks its working @TobiasK

Comment: Great. I added it as an answer, if you want to accept/close that question.

Answer (score 1):

The directory where it installed/linked the tool needs to be in your `PATH` variable if you want to call it just by its name.

So either:

- Add `/home/dell/.npm-global/bin` to your `PATH`
- Call it via its "full name/path": `/home/dell/.npm-global/bin/create-nuxt-app myapp`